# Orphan management with AWS DynamoDB & S3 data spread across multiple items & buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB items are currently limited to a 400KB maximum size. When storing items longer than this limit, Amazon [suggests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForItems.html#GuidelinesForItems.StoringInS3) a few options, including splitting long items into multiple items, splitting items across tables,  and/or storing large data in S3.

Sounds OK if nothing ever failed. But what's a recommended approach to deal with making updates and deletes consistent across multiple DynamoDB items plus, just to make things interesting, S3 buckets too?

For a concrete example, imagine an email app with:

- EmailHeader table in DynamoDB
- EmailBodyChunk table in DynamoDB
- EmailAttachment table in DynamoDB that points to email attachments stored in S3 buckets

Let's say I want to delete an email. What's a good approach to make sure that orphan data will get cleaned up if something goes wrong during the delete operation and data is only partially deleted?  (Ideally, it'd be a solution that won't add additional operational complexity like having to temporarily increase the provisioned read limit to run a garbage-collector script.)

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of alternatives for your use case:

- Use the [DynamoDB transactions](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions) library that:

> enables Java developers to easily perform atomic writes and isolated reads across multiple items and tables when building high scale applications on Amazon DynamoDB.

It is important to note that it requires 7N+4 writes, which'll be costly. So, go this route only if you require strong ACID properties, such as for banking or other monetary applications.

- If you are okay with the DB being inconsistent for a short duration, you can perform the required operations one by one and mark the entire thing *complete* only at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could manage your deletion events with an [SQS queue that supports exactly-once semantics](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/) and use that queue to start a [Step workflow](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) that deletes the corresponding header, body chunk and attachment. In retrospect, the queue does not even need to be exactly once, as you can just stop a workflow in case the header does not exist.